# Running QuickBooks PHP DevKit - IPP Intuit Anywhere Demo App on Localhost

Tags: php, api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Good Day,

I just downloaded and installed on my localhost QuickBooks PHP DevKit - IPP Intuit Anywhere Demo App from [github](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php).

I then tried to access "example_app_ipp_v3" folder to get my app running
 (configured the config.php too)

```
<?php

/**
 * Intuit Partner Platform configuration variables
 * 
 * See the scripts that use these variables for more details. 
 * 
 * @package QuickBooks
 * @subpackage Documentation
 */

// Turn on some error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Require the library code
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../QuickBooks.php';

// Your application token (Intuit will give you this when you register an Intuit Anywhere app)
$token = '961a033ab1294b4499bb04dbd0d14744c9ba';
// $token = '96262faa-cf42-424a-b7ff-7637a939a591';

// Your OAuth consumer key and secret (Intuit will give you both of these when you register an Intuit app)
// 
// IMPORTANT:
//  To pass your tech review with Intuit, you'll have to AES encrypt these and 
//  store them somewhere safe. 
// 
// The OAuth request/access tokens will be encrypted and stored for you by the 
//  PHP DevKit IntuitAnywhere classes automatically. 
$oauth_consumer_key = 'qyprdZ5wvJ7vfPWWl0ez5kMRJlTF5H';
$oauth_consumer_secret = 'qv46uqwMemeMCb2FqllAnjOYMf4T4YOwU9eL02HG';

// If you're using DEVELOPMENT TOKENS, you MUST USE SANDBOX MODE!!!  If you're in PRODUCTION, then DO NOT use sandbox.
$sandbox = true;     // When you're using development tokens
//$sandbox = false;    // When you're using production tokens

// This is the URL of your OAuth auth handler page
$quickbooks_oauth_url = 'http://qbintegrations.com/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php';

// This is the URL to forward the user to after they have connected to IPP/IDS via OAuth
$quickbooks_success_url = 'http://qbintegrations.com/quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/success.php';

// This is the menu URL script 
$quickbooks_menu_url = 'http://qbintegrations.com/quickbooks-php/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/menu.php';

// This is a database connection string that will be used to store the OAuth credentials 
// $dsn = 'pgsql://username:password@hostname/database';
// $dsn = 'mysql://username:password@hostname/database';
$dsn = 'mysqli://root:hack2help@localhost/qb_db';

// You should set this to an encryption key specific to your app
$encryption_key = 'bcde1234';

// Do not change this unless you really know what you're doing!!!  99% of apps will not require a change to this.
$the_username = 'DO_NOT_CHANGE_ME';
```

But when I click the Connect Button I got this error..

[image]

I tried to upload the same file on an online web server and I successfully connected to QB then..
(slight configuration on config.php [database and url] but same token used )

by the way.. it was set up on virtual host too..

Now I want to successfully connect on my localhost so I could develop faster.
 Can you help me please:) Thanks!

Comment: Are you using your SANDBOX/DEVELOPMENT credentials from Intuit (and NOT your production ones)? Are you sure you have the URLs set correctly within Intuit's control panel thing? It sounds like you're bouncing between environments and probably have something mismatched.

Comment: Hi Sir.. Thanks for passing by.. Yes.. I am using my Development Credentials .. and maybe your right with the URL thing.. Im not sure whats wrong with it though.. since I set up my vhost to "qbintegrations.com" also added it to my host file.. qbintegrations.com 127.0.0.1... so in my localhost copy I set them to qbintegrations.com/etc... as well..

Comment: like what mismatched Sir? for example? since I just copy paste from my config online to my localhost and "changed url and db credentials only"